# How to get object from OneToMany collection of objects?

Tags: java, json, spring, hibernate, jpa

I have an `Order` entity and `OrderProduct`. I want to show order details on frontend and of course order products in it. So how to fetch product object in `OrderProduct` JSON. I'm missing product object in products array. I don't need order object one more time and i think it going to be a infinite recursion stuff with it. :)

My `Order` entity:

```java
@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
@Table(name ="orders")
public class Order{

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    public Long id;

    private BigDecimal totalPrice;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "order", fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JsonManagedReference(value="orders")
    private List<OrderProduct> products = new ArrayList<>();

    private int userId;

    @DateTimeFormat(pattern="dd/MM/yyyy")
    private Date date = new Date();

    @DateTimeFormat(pattern="dd/MM/yyyy")
    private Date deliveryDate;

    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private OrderType orderType;

}
```

My `OrderProduct` entity:

```java
@Entity
@Setter
@Getter
public class OrderProduct {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JsonBackReference(value="product")
    @JoinColumn(name = "product_id")
    private Product product;

    @ManyToOne
    @JsonBackReference(value="orders")
    @JoinColumn(name = "order_id")
    private Order order;

    private Integer quantity;
}
```

Product entity:

```java
@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
public class Product {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Column(unique = true)
    private String name;

    private double price;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "product", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JsonManagedReference(value="ingredients")
    private List<Ingredient> ingredients = new ArrayList<>();

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "product",fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JsonManagedReference(value="product")
    private List<OrderProduct> products = new ArrayList<>();

    private String fileName;

}
```

[image: order JSON]

Answer (score 0):

This can help annotate one of your entity clases with

```
@JsonIdentityInfo(
    property = "id",
    generator = ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class
)
```

Every time when JSON serialization go in circles object data will be replaced with object id or orher field of entity for your choose.

Comment: Unfortunately this is not working for me. I've tried this. I've added this code into in  my entity seperately and it's still the same. I'm still missing product Object in products[].

Answer (score 0):

You can use `@JsonView`annotation to define the fields that you need to serialize to JSON

How it works:

1. You need define class with interfaces. For example:

   ```
   public class SomeView {

       public interface  id {}

       public interface CoreData extends id {}

       public interface FullData extends CoreData {}

   }
   ```
2. Mark entity fields with `@JsonView(<some interface.class>)`

   ```
   public class User {

       @Id
       @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
       @JsonView(SomeView.id.class)
       private Long id;

       @Column(nullable = false)
       @JsonView(SomeView.CoreData.class)
       private String username;

       @Column(nullable = false)
       @JsonView(SomeView.FullData.class)
       private String email;
   }
   ```
3. Annotate endpoint with `@JsonView(<some interface.class>)`

   ```
    @GetMapping()
    @JsonView(<some interface.class>)
    public User getUser() {
        return <get user entity somwhere>
    }
   ```

In case `@JsonView(SomeView.id.class)` you will get this JSON:

```
    {
        id: <some id>
    }
```

In case `@JsonView(SomeView.CoreData.class)`:

```
    {
        id: <some id>,
        username: <some username>
    }
```

In case `@JsonView(SomeView.FullData.class)`:

```
    {
        id: <some id>,
        username: <some username>,
        email: <some email>
    }
```

`@JsonView` also works with embeded objects and you can annotate one field with multiply views classes - `@JsonView({SomeView.FullData.class, SomeOtherView.OtherData.class})`

In your case i think you should annotate all the fields you need except:

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "product",fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JsonManagedReference(value="product")
private List<OrderProduct> products = new ArrayList<>();
```

in `Product`

to avoid circular serialization

Or as alternative you can just use DTO classes or seralize oject to JSON manualy (https://thepracticaldeveloper.com/java-and-json-jackson-serialization-with-objectmapper/)

Answer (score 0):

This can be done by my library [beanknife](https://github.com/vipcxj/beanknife)

```java
// This configure generate a class named ProductInfo which has the same shape with Product without property "products"
@ViewOf(value = Product.class, genName="ProductInfo", includePattern = ".*", excludes = {"products"})
class ProductInfoConfigure {}

// This configure generate a class named OrderProductRelation with the same shape of OrderProduct.
// But it has not order property and the type of its product property is change to ProductInfo generated above.
@ViewOf(value = OrderProduct.class, genName="OrderProductRelation", includePattern = ".*", excludes = {"order"})
class OrderProductRelationConfigure {
    @OverrideViewProperty("product")
    private ProductInfo product;
}

// This configure generate a class named OrderDetail with the same shape of Order. 
// But the type of its products property is change to List<OrderProductRelation>
@ViewOf(value = Order.class, genName="OrderDetail", includePattern = ".*")
class OrderDetailConfigure {
    @OverrideViewProperty("products")
    private List<OrderProductRelation> products;
}
```

will generate these classes:

```java
class ProductInfo {
    private Long id;
    private String name;
    private double price;
    private List<Ingredient> ingredients; // it is not processed because you have not provide the class Ingredient
    private String fileName;
}

public class OrderProductRelation {
    private Long id;
    private ProductInfo product;
    private Integer quantity;
}

public class OrderDetail {
    public Long id;
    private BigDecimal totalPrice;
    private List<OrderProductRelation> products;
    private int userId;
    private Date date = new Date();
    private Date deliveryDate;
    private OrderType orderType;
}
```

Then

```java
Order order = ...
OrderDetail orderDetail = OrderDetail.read(order);
// serialize the otherDetail instead of order.

List<Order> orders = ...
List<OrderDetail> orderDetails = OrderDetail.read(orders);
// serialize the orderDetails instead of orders.
```

Possible problems:

1. I doesn't use Lombok, so Lombok may need to be adapted because it change the byte code on the fly. But it is not a big problem, I will try to adapt it if someone commit the issue and provide enough use cases.
2. The generated class does not inherit the annotation on the original class. In next release I will provide a sulotion. At this moment, as a workaround, we can use custom method to convert the property manually. such as

```java
@ViewOf(value = Order.class, genName="OrderDetail", includePattern = ".*")
class OrderDetailConfigure {
    @OverrideViewProperty("products")
    private List<OrderProductRelation> products;
    @OverrideViewProperty("orderType")
    public static String orderType(Order source) {
        return source.getOrder().name();
    }
}
```

The generated class will be changed to

```java
public class OrderDetail {
    public Long id;
    private BigDecimal totalPrice;
    private List<OrderProductRelation> products;
    private int userId;
    private Date date = new Date();
    private Date deliveryDate;
    private String orderType;
}
```

**Update**
Version 1.2.0 released. Add support of annotation inheritance.

```java
@ViewOf(value = Order.class, genName="OrderDetail", includePattern = ".*")
@UseAnnotation({DateTimeFormat.class, Enumerated.class, JsonProperty.class})
class OrderDetailConfigure {
    @OverrideViewProperty("products")
    private List<OrderProductRelation> products;
}
```

generate

```java
public class OrderDetail {
    public Long id;
    private BigDecimal totalPrice;
    private List<OrderProductRelation> products;
    private int userId;
    @DateTimeFormat(pattern="dd/MM/yyyy")
    private Date date;
    @DateTimeFormat(pattern="dd/MM/yyyy")
    private Date deliveryDate;
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private OrderType orderType;
}
```